# Will System.Random always generate predictable numbers for a given seed across platforms?

Tags: c#, .net, random

I know that Object.GetHashCode can return different values for the same object (an identical string, for example) depending on the platform.  I thus can't rely on this for a cross-platform simple hash.

But can I rely on System.Random?  Will it produce the same results for a given seed regardless of whether or not I'm on Microsoft .NET / Mono / x86 / x64, etc.?

Comment: I would suggest that relying on a class called "Random" to give predictable numbers would be a mistake :)

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee that they won't change the algorithm at some point...

Comment: Did you new Random in loop?

Comment: @DavidG It is very common to rely on a random number generator to produce predictable results given a specific seed, for reproducing issues deterministically, etc.

Comment: @LeiYang I am very familiar with the issue you're addressing but that's not the issue I'm having.  I need a guaranteed identical hash value across any platform.

Comment: @vargonian It may be common, but it's not a good idea.

Comment: @DavidG In that case, how instead would you suggest reproducing gameplay scenarios, etc. deterministically given that they involve many RNG calculations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Jeremy mentioned [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42823341/80274) the documentation states that the number generator is not guaranteed consistent across .NET versions.

However, the documentation also tells you [how to implement your algorithm too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-6.0#substituting-your-own-algorithm).

> You can implement your own random number generator by inheriting from the Random class and supplying your random number generation algorithm. To supply your own algorithm, you must override the `Sample` method, which implements the random number generation algorithm. You should also override the `Next()`, `Next(Int32, Int32)`, and `NextBytes` methods to ensure that they call your overridden Sample method. You don't have to override the `Next(Int32)` and `NextDouble` methods.

Using that we can make our own random class that uses a known fixed algorithm you can use. For example, we could go [to the .Net source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.7/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Random.cs) and implement the current random algorithm, this would allow us to use the `ConsistantRandom` class and know for sure the algorithom won't change on us.

The following example is derived from [the .NET Core 1.1.0 source](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/release/1.1.0/src/mscorlib/src/System/Random.cs/).

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class ConsistantRandom: Random
    {
        private const int MBIG = Int32.MaxValue;
        private const int MSEED = 161803398;
        private const int MZ = 0;

        private int inext;
        private int inextp;
        private int[] SeedArray = new int[56];

        public ConsistantRandom()
            : this(Environment.TickCount)
        {
        }

        public ConsistantRandom(int seed)
        {
            int ii;
            int mj, mk;

            int subtraction = (seed == Int32.MinValue) ? Int32.MaxValue : Math.Abs(seed);
            mj = MSEED - subtraction;
            SeedArray[55] = mj;
            mk = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < 55; i++)
            {
                ii = (21 * i) % 55;
                SeedArray[ii] = mk;
                mk = mj - mk;
                if (mk < 0) mk += MBIG;
                mj = SeedArray[ii];
            }
            for (int k = 1; k < 5; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 56; i++)
                {
                    SeedArray[i] -= SeedArray[1 + (i + 30) % 55];
                    if (SeedArray[i] < 0) SeedArray[i] += MBIG;
                }
            }
            inext = 0;
            inextp = 21;
        }
        protected override double Sample()
        {
            return (InternalSample() * (1.0 / MBIG));
        }

        private int InternalSample()
        {
            int retVal;
            int locINext = inext;
            int locINextp = inextp;

            if (++locINext >= 56) locINext = 1;
            if (++locINextp >= 56) locINextp = 1;

            retVal = SeedArray[locINext] - SeedArray[locINextp];

            if (retVal == MBIG) retVal--;
            if (retVal < 0) retVal += MBIG;

            SeedArray[locINext] = retVal;

            inext = locINext;
            inextp = locINextp;

            return retVal;
        }

        public override int Next()
        {
            return InternalSample();
        }

        private double GetSampleForLargeRange()
        {
            int result = InternalSample();
            bool negative = (InternalSample() % 2 == 0) ? true : false;
            if (negative)
            {
                result = -result;
            }
            double d = result;
            d += (Int32.MaxValue - 1);
            d /= 2 * (uint)Int32.MaxValue - 1;
            return d;
        }


        public override int Next(int minValue, int maxValue)
        {
            if (minValue > maxValue)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("minValue");
            }

            long range = (long)maxValue - minValue;
            if (range <= (long)Int32.MaxValue)
            {
                return ((int)(Sample() * range) + minValue);
            }
            else
            {
                return (int)((long)(GetSampleForLargeRange() * range) + minValue);
            }
        }
        public override void NextBytes(byte[] buffer)
        {
            if (buffer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            {
                buffer[i] = (byte)(InternalSample() % (Byte.MaxValue + 1));
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Because `ConsistantRandom` derives from `Random` you can use the class as a drop in replacement anywhere you had the type `Random` before, you just need to replace `Random rnd = new Random(yourSeed);` with `Random rnd = new ConsistantRandom(yourSeed);`.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can not rely on consistent values being generated across platforms or versions. From [the .NET Framework docs for `System.Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) (the less-detailed [.NET Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.random) don't address this):

> The implementation of the random number generator in the Random class isn't guaranteed to remain the same across major versions of the .NET Framework. As a result, you shouldn't assume that the same seed will result in the same pseudo-random sequence in different versions of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for and I'm ashamed I didn't catch this in the docs.  Now I've got to search for something that will be guaranteed to be predictable, or write my own (since it doesn't need to be fancy).

Comment: @vargonian: I've put together a simple PRNG here that you can take or improve on if you wish: https://gist.github.com/caesay/5f79b958c025db084dcdfb50f69ce039

Comment: @vargonian FYI [the source code for Microsoft's current built-in implementation is available under the MIT license](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/release/1.1.0/src/mscorlib/src/System/Random.cs/), so you could use a renamed copy of that and be safe and consistent.